# select where maximum date

Tags: sql, date, max, where-clause

I have a table `table1` where I want to do a case statement that selects an employee ID based on the most recent hire date. An employee can have 2 separate user ID's in the system, I wanted to grab the user ID that was most recent. I tried approaching this by joining the fica_nbr of the employee from another table (table2), that way if it shows up more than once, I know the employee has 2 different hire dates and I can go

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(table2.fica_nbr) > 1
            THEN SELECT(table1.employeeID)
                 WHERE employeeID is MAX date /*->This is the line im having trouble on, how would I get the employee ID that is the most up to date using the where clause*/
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this
change colunms with your required colunms

```
 SELECT report_id, computer_id, date_entered
    FROM reports AS a
    WHERE date_entered = (
        SELECT MAX(date_entered)
        FROM reports AS b
        WHERE a.report_id = b.report_id
          AND a.computer_id = b.computer_id
    )
```